# Food API Endpoints - Query by FEI number?

Tags: data-request, api, food

we are trying to figure out how to query the Food API endpoint using the FEI number and pulling back Recall Enforcement and Adverse Events Reports. So far we cannot find any way to query this data using the FEI number. Does anybody know if this is possible?